# how to ensure that other user does not add new items when merge two registers?

Tags: c#, sqlite, transactions

I am using SQLite and C# and I have this case. I have a Persons table and other with Cars. The relation is 1:N, one person can have many cars and a car is only of one person.

Well, imagine that I have two registers but rally are the same person, so I want to merge the two persons in only one.

So I the idea is:

1.- I choose the correct person.
2.- I select all the cars of the incorrect person
3.- I set the IDPerson of the cars of the incorrect person to IDPerson of the correct person.

The problem is that between I load all the cars of the incorrect person and chenge the IDPerson, other usr can assign a new car to the incorrect person, so this new car would have the IDPerson of the incorrect person because is not included in the result of the query when I get all the cars of the incorrect person.

In SQL Server for example I use to use a transaction to block the incorrect person to ensure that a second user can't assign a new car to the incorrect person, but in SQL Lite I can't block the register, because if I use a transaction block the mdb and I get an error.

So I would like to know an alternative way to ensure that nobody can add new cars to the incorrect person while the first user is merging the two persons.

Thanks.

Comment: How long does the transaction actually run? Have you configured a timeout?

Comment: Well, in SQLite when I try to use a transaction I get an error because the database file is blocked and I don't be able to use a transaction in SQLite. So the transaction does not take place.

Comment: The database file is locked as long as *another* transaction is running. I was asking about that one.